# Eonsdan-datetimepicker How to set default date in Input when opens first time

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

im setting default date in Eonasdan-Bootstrap datetimepicker like this

```
$('#frmDate').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(moment().subtract(14, "days").calendar());
```

I know `useCurrent` will not fire. but I want to fire it so that when I open calendar first time it should intialized input with default date

Comment: what is your default date ?

Comment: Can you show your datetimepicker init code? Why can't you use [`defaultDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option instead of [`defaultDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#defaultdate) function?

Comment: Vin@VincenzoC both are same things, Im intializing many datepickers in itializing code. Only want to have some different default date for specific datepickers only, so I have to do it in separate

Comment: Ok, I understand, I think that you have to remove `.calendar()` to make it work, you will have: `$('#frmDate').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(moment().subtract(14, "days"));`